# Is it possible to add new permissions to the System Administrator profile

Tags: profile

Pretty sure the answer is no, as its not possible to edit the system administrator profile, but just in case...here goes.

When new permissions are created by Salesforce, is there any way to get these included for the system administrator profile **itself** (ie not by creating a new permission set and assigning it).

I'm testing API client whitelisting in my sandbox, and the new `Use Any API Client` permission was not added to the system administrator profile. In looking, I noticed the new-ish `set audit fields upon creation` is also not enabled, along with a few others here and there.

[image: a few missing permissions from standard system admin profile]

My general sense was that the standard system admin profile is granted all permissions by default.  I do wonder if these permissions would be checked in a new org. Spun up a new DE org and dont see many of the perms in there at all, so going to consider this a moot point and close the question.

So if there is any way to add the permission, would be interested to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a Permission sets, one for individual setting (or for a few related), using the same name as setting - e.g. `Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation` and assign to admin users, and anyone else you want.

> **Tip** You can leave 'User License' blank and it will allow to apply the same Permission Set to many types of user accounts - like `Salesforce` and `Force.com`

Comment: Thanks, understand I can create perm set, curious if there is any option or way to enable for the admin profile itself, perhaps through sfdc support, etc.  I have updated question to reflect that.

Comment: I believe the reason why they do not allow modifications to standard profiles and enabling just some of the features is a versions compatibility - by making sure that all users on standard profiles would not run into any issues caused by eliminated features